# FXML importing static nested class

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Suppose I have a custom JavaFX control `Foo` with a specialized case implemented as a nested static class `Foo$Bar`:

```
package com.acme; 

import javafx.scene.control.Control;

public class Foo extends Control {
    public static class Bar extends Foo {
    }
}
```

Now I may want to use this control in an FXML, so I expect I should do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import com.acme.Foo$Bar?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.191" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <Foo.Bar/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

However, this results in the FXML being unloadable, raising the error

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: Foo.Bar is not a valid type.

Curiously, if I change the import to read:

```
<?import com.acme.Foo.Bar?>
```

the FXML loads correctly, but my IDE (IntelliJ) marks the import as erroneous - I tend to agree with it, as it seems the FXML specification calls for importing using the fully-qualified class name, which in this case would be `com.acme.Foo$Bar` and not `com.acme.Foo.Bar`.

So is this a bug in JavaFX/`FXMLLoader` not recognizing fully-qualified names of static nested classes? Or is it a bug in IntelliJ, not recognizing a (poorly-documented?) legal import?

Comment: I'm inclined to think the issue is on Intellij's side and the [FXML documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements) perhaps used a poor choice of words. The use of `.` instead of `$` is consistent with Java source code for both importing and when using the fully-qualified name. However, even with importing you still have to use `<Foo.Bar/>` instead of `<Bar/>` lest it throw an exception saying `Bar` is not a valid type. This is inconsistent with Java source code.

Comment: Also, Intellij is not fully compliant with the FXML specs anyway. An example would be [this functionality](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#collections_and_property_handlers); when using it Intellij marks it as invalid.

Comment: Probably should have searched for a bug before posting here - there is a report from 8 months ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190964

Comment: There's also a bug report for the issue I mentioned in my second comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184839